# Arrays Random Multiplication Math

Tags: python

This is an Arrays Random Math program that I am having trouble with. The program is to prompt the user to solve 5 random multiplication math problems. The first number is to be from 1 to 12 and the second number from 5 to 15. Both numbers are to be stored in arrays. I have to display the question on the screen and prompt the user to enter the correct answer. Then I have to store the user's answers in an third array. Next I have to display the questions in two groups with headings.

For example

Correct Answers

5 x 12 = 60

4 x 10 = 40

9 x 12 = 108

Incorrect Answers

12 x 12 = 142

8 x 13 = 94

At the end, I have to tell the user how many they got correct out of 5.

Here is my code so far:

```
SB=''
import random

N1=[0 for x in range(5)]
for i in range(5):
    N1[i]=random.randrange(13)

N2=[0 for x in range(5)]
for i in range(5):
    N2[i]=random.randrange(16)

ANS=[0 for x in range(5)]
for i in range(5):
    Q=print(N1[i],'x',N2[i])
    C=N1[i]*N2[i]
    ANS[i]=int(input('Enter an Anwser:'))
    if ANS[i]==C:
        print('Correct')
    elif ANS[i]!=C:
        print('Incorrect')
    print(SB)

for i in range(5):
    ANS[i]=Q

print('Correct Anwsers')
for i in range(5):
    if ANS[i]==C:
        print(N1[i],'x',N2[i],ANS[i])

print('Incorrect Anwsers')
for i in range(5):
    if ANS[i]==C:
        print(N1[i],'x',N2[i],'=',ANS[i])
```

I am having trouble with storing the user's answers in a third array and then displaying them in the two categories of Correct and Incorrect Answers for the way I want them displayed as shown above. I am also having trouble with figuring  out the accumulator. If you could help me figure this code out, that would be great. Thank you.

Comment: Fix your indentation... _please_.

Comment: thank you i edited the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just hace to remove a loop code because you where asigning the value Q to all the answers. Also, when you compare at the two last loops the answer with C, you are allways comparing with the last C value. The code you must remove is:

```
  for i in range(5):
    ANS[i]=Q
```

This is the right code:

```
SB=''
import random

N1=[0 for x in range(5)]
for i in range(5):
    N1[i]=random.randrange(13)

N2=[0 for x in range(5)]
for i in range(5):
    N2[i]=random.randrange(16)

ANS=[0 for x in range(5)]
for i in range(5):
    print(N1[i],'x',N2[i])
    C=N1[i]*N2[i]
    ANS[i]=int(input('Enter an Anwser:'))
    if ANS[i]==C:
        print('Correct')
    elif ANS[i]!=C:
        print('Incorrect')
    print(SB)

print('Correct Anwsers')
for i in range(5):
    if ANS[i]==N1[i]*N2[i]:
        print(N1[i],'x',N2[i],ANS[i])

print('Incorrect Anwsers')
for i in range(5):
    if ANS[i]!=N1[i]*N2[i]:
        print(N1[i],'x',N2[i],'=',ANS[i])
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning `Q` the return value of `print()` which is `NoneType`

```
Q=print(N1[i],'x',N2[i])
```

You are also overwriting your `ANS` list with the value NoneType:

```
for i in range(5):
    ANS[i]=Q
```

You are also checking the `ANS` list for Correct and Incorrect using the same conditional:

```
if ANS[i]==C:
```

That conditional will not work correctly, in that loop C is never updated. You are checking every answer against the same value of C which happens to be:

```
C=N1[i]*N2[i]
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be that you are comparing `ANS` to the most recent value of `C` rather than the answer to the question. `Q` is unnecessary but you can store the answers in a list instead.

There was also a couple mistakes including no = on correct answers, it is possible to get 0 as the first number and the last didn't have to be higher than 5 which I've fixed too.

Here's my version of the code:

```
SB=''
import random

N1=[0 for x in range(5)]
for i in range(5):
    N1[i]=random.randrange(1, 13)

N2=[0 for x in range(5)]
for i in range(5):
    N2[i]=random.randrange(5, 16)

ANS=[0 for x in range(5)]
C=[0 for x in range(5)]
for i in range(5):
    C[i]=N1[i]*N2[i]
    print(N1[i],'x',N2[i])
    ANS[i]=int(input('Enter an Anwser:'))
    if ANS[i]==C[i]:
        print('Correct')
    elif ANS[i]!=C[i]:
        print('Incorrect')
    print(SB)

print('Correct Anwsers')
for i in range(5):
    if ANS[i]==C[i]:
        print(N1[i],'x',N2[i], '=', ANS[i])

print('Incorrect Anwsers')
for i in range(5):
    if ANS[i]==C[i]:
        print(N1[i],'x',N2[i],'=',ANS[i])
```

Hope this helped!